# Select2 Version 4.0.1 upgrade initSelection

Tags: jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2

I have been using Select2 version 3 for my dropdowns for a while. However, I am trying to upgrade to the latest v4 release and am struggling to understand their documentation. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction in converting the below v3.5 code to v4 so that I can understand how to convert the rest of my code?

```
    $("#@hp.ID").select2(
    {
        dropdownAutoWidth: true,
        minimumInputLength: 0,
        allowClear: getBool("@hp.bAllowClear"),
        width: "@hp.Width",
        formatResult: formatResults,
        formatSelection: formatSelection,
        matcher: SetMatcher,
        sortResults: SortSelect2,
        initSelection: function (element, callback)
        {
            var id = "@Model"
            if ((id != "") && (id != "0") && (id != undefined))
            {
                $.ajax("@Url.Action("GetVendorsInit", "DropDownManagerAjax")",
                {
                    data: JSON.stringify({ VendorID: id }),
                    dataType: "json"
                }).done(function (data)
                {
                    callback({ id: data.id, text: data.text });
                });
            }
        },
        ajax: {
            url: "@Url.Action("GetVendors", "DropDownManagerAjax")",
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 250,
            data: function (term, page)
            {
                return {
                    q: term,
                    iDisplayStart: (page - 1) * 100,
                    iDisplayLength: 100,
                    sEcho: 0,
                    iSortCol_0: 0,
                    sSortDir_0: 'asc',
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page)
            {
                var more = (page * 30) <= data.total;
                return { results: data.data, more: more };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        dropdownCssClass: "autoWidth",
        escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; },
        placeholder: 'Select Vendor...'
    });
```

Comment: This is the question we all are asking, read this https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3116